# Sort a set in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sorting, collections

Framework used: Spring

ORM used: Hibernate

I have two classes

```
class BatchExceptionDetails{
...
private Set<BatchExceptionComments> batchExceptionComments;
}

class BatchExceptionComments implements Comparable<BatchExceptionComments>{
...
@Override
    public int compareTo(BatchExceptionComments o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return this.getAddedOn().compareTo(o.getAddedOn());
    }
}
```

They are mapped with one to many mapping.

There is a set of BatchExceptionComments in BatchExceptionDetails.

I want to sort the set on the basis of Date. BatchExcpetionComment has an attribute of type java.util.Date i.e. addedOn. I want the latest comment to be the first element of set.

The set I am receiving is not sorted. Will you please guide me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using a `SortedSet`? Or some other type of `Set`?

Comment: `Collections.sort(batchExceptionComments);`

Comment: @Lorelorelore That's only available for lists, not for sets.

Comment: @JoeC, I am using just Set

Comment: Sets are unsorted. Use a list instead.

Comment: You can't be using just `Set`, because `Set` is an interface.  What implementation of `Set` are you using?

Comment: You could also use order by clause on the date column (order by date desc) when you query the database. Another option would be to display the result in reverse order

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, That is why I used comparator. I have to use set.

Comment: @sticky_elbows, As the mapping is already done, I am just fetching BatchExceptionDetails, because of mapping I am automatically getting BAtchExceptionComment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some goofing around I found a solution.

I just declared the set

```
private Set<BatchExceptionComments> batchExceptionComments;
```

Instead of using Comparable I used Order By to arrange the set.

```
 <set name="batchExceptionComments" table="BATCH_EXCEPTION_COMMENTS" 
                inverse="true" fetch="select" lazy="false" order-by="commentId">
            <key>
                <column name="EXCEPTION_ID" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.beans.BatchExceptionComments" />
        </set>
```

I believe ordering by Id will be better.

P.S. I am using hbm.xml instead of annotation

Answer (score 7):

`Set` is an interface, so it is not possible to establish if it is sortable or not. You have to use the correct implementation, like [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). If you want to 
emphasize that it is a sorted set, you should use the `SortedSet` interface. `TreeSet` implements `SortedSet`.

Alternatively you can use a `List` and then you can sort it using `Collections.sort`.

Comment: Can I use other collections instead of Set ? I am in assumption that if we are using Spring then we have to use Set for Containment.

Comment: The problem is that Hibernate requires collections to be specified as an interface type. In terms of implementation classes, it uses its own to support things like lazy loading. Specifying the type as `SortedSet` instead of `Set` should work though.

Comment: No need to initialize it. Hibernate will automatically initialize it with its own `SortedSet` implementation.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, I used SortedSet and I am getting an exception    IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [combeans.BatchExceptionDetails.batchExceptionComments (expected type = java.util.SortedSet)];

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, my setter method is  public void setBatchExceptionComments(
   SortedSet<BatchExceptionComments> batchExceptionComments) {
  this.batchExceptionComments = batchExceptionComments;
 }

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, declaration is private SortedSet<BatchExceptionComments> batchExceptionComments;

Comment: Take a look at this [article](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ordering-vs-sorting-hibernate-use/). It lists up all the common use cases.